# Getting null value for the Scenario Context- cucumber pico container

Tags: testng, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, picocontainer

Getting null value when tried to get the value in steps given in second scenario. However I am able to get the value, when I tried in same steps.

```
Feature File
Feature: 01_Permission_Accept

  Scenario: 01_Is AUT installed and click on chapter 1
    Given Check AUT is installed  --> Here I am setting the value to context
    When Click on chapter - Chapter 1: App Fundamentals --> Here the value is retrieved

  Scenario: 02_Click on chapter 2
    When Click on demo chapter - Chapter 2: User Interface --> Here the value is null
```

Definition file:

```
public class MainScreenStepDefs {

TestContext testContext;

public MainScreenStepDefs(TestContext context) {
    this.testContext = context;
}

@Given("Check AUT is installed")
public void checkAUTIsInstalled() {
    boolean abc = testContext.getAppiumDriver().isAppInstalled(testContext.getConfiguration().androidAppPackage());
    SoftAssertions.assertSoftly(softAssertions -> softAssertions.assertThat(abc).as("Application \"" +testContext.getConfiguration().androidAppPackage()+"\" is not installed.").isTrue());
    testContext.getScenarioContext().setContext(ContextEnum.DEMO, "demo"); // Setting value to context
}

@When("Click on chapter - Chapter 1: App Fundamentals")
public void clickOnChapter1() {
    testContext.getPageObjectManager().getMainScreen().selectChapter1();
    String abc  = (String) testContext.getScenarioContext().getContext(ContextEnum.DEMO);
    System.out.println("Data :--------------- \t" + abc); //value getting successfully
}

@When("Click on demo chapter - Chapter 2: User Interface")
public void clickOnDemoChapter2() {
    testContext.getPageObjectManager().getMainScreen().selectChapter2();
    String abc  = (String) testContext.getScenarioContext().getContext(ContextEnum.DEMO);
    System.out.println("Data :--------------- \t" + abc); // ----null value
}}
```

Test Runner File. I am using TestNg as Runner. Inside @Beforesuite I am calling driver. here using @BeforeSuite, to avoid test to be closed after each scenario.

Using Lombok for getter and setter.

```
public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    @Getter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
    private DriverManager mobileDriverManager;

    public static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> appiumDriver; // making static so this can be accessed directly
    Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration();

    @BeforeSuite(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setup() {
        mobileDriverManager = DriverFactory.getMobileDriverManager(DeviceTypeEnum.ANDROID);
        appiumDriver = mobileDriverManager.getMobileDriver(configuration.androidPlatformAndVersion(), configuration.androidDeviceUDID(), configuration.androidSystemPort(), AutomationName.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR2);
    }

    @AfterSuite(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDown() {
        getMobileDriverManager().quitAppiumDriver();
    }
}
```

TestContext.java
Here before initilizing PageObjectManager, I am setting the AppiumDriver. Not doing so was giving error.

```
public class TestContext {

    @Getter @Setter
    private AppiumDriver<MobileElement> appiumDriver;

    @Getter
    private ScenarioContext scenarioContext;

    @Getter
    private PageObjectManager pageObjectManager;

    @Getter
    private Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration();

    public TestContext() {
        setAppiumDriver(TestRunner.appiumDriver); // This gives error, If I remove this.
        pageObjectManager = new PageObjectManager(getAppiumDriver());
        scenarioContext = new ScenarioContext();
    }
}
```

Please let me know am I doing the correct pico-container implementation.

Here is sample application github link: https://github.com/dipakkumar1225/DemoCucumberPicoContainerTestng.git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects are persisted along the single scenario. You set the value in one scenario and try to read it in another. This is why you get `null`.

> Dependency Injection allows you to share the state between **steps** - not between scenarios.

If you have something to set up for each scenario you need to deal with [Background](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#background).